# Live Agent Deployment: why does Salesforce recommend a particular place for the generated code?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

The documentation on Live Agent Deployment states: "Copy the [generated] deployment code and paste it on each Web page where you want to deploy Live Agent. For best performance, paste the code right before the closing body tag (that is, `</body>`)."

The last sentence triggers my curiosity: what exactly is meant with performance? Why would that performance be best when the code is pasted right there? How can Salesforce make this recommendation, regardless of the used web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html says:

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads.
>   The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more
>   than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images
>   from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur
>   in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't
>   start any other downloads, even on different hostnames. In some
>   situations it's not easy to move scripts to the bottom. If, for
>   example, the script uses document.write to insert part of the page's
>   content, it can't be moved lower in the page. There might also be
>   scoping issues. In many cases, there are ways to workaround these
>   situations. An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use
>   deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does
>   not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can
>   continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER
>   attribute. In Internet Explorer, the script may be deferred, but not
>   as much as desired. If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved
>   to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.

Comment: I am slightly suspicious by the fact that your last name matches OP's. Conspiracy? You decide!=)

Comment: De Jong is the most common last name in The Netherlands. Like Smith in the States.